# Understanding three prisoners problem

Tags: probability

I briefly state the problem: There are 3 prisoners. One of them is going to be executed. Prisoner A asks the warden to tell him name of 1 prisoner who will not be executed tomorrow. Warden tells him that C will not be executed. After warden's answer, A becomes anxious, because before this information his chance of being executed was 1/3 and now **it seems** it has become 1/2. He says to himself what a mistake I made in asking the warden.

Now I want to formulate this problem with Bayes formula.

1. Is it correct to have three random variables each named after one
   prisoner, i.e. A, B, C? Or there is only A and C as random variables?
2. Should  I draw a chance tree with three nodes for the execution of each one, which at the outset each one has an equal chance of 1/3. The tree only forks on A because if he is to be executed the warden can name either B or C which the probability of each one becomes 1/6. For the case of execution of B or C the waren won't name A and only name either one which is not going to be executed.
   a. if A executed then warden names B or C each with chance of 1/2 which multiplied by 1./3 chance of A becomes 1/6.

   b. if B executed then Warden only names C which is 1/3(of B) multiplied by the only probable name C which is 1.

   c. if C executed then waren only names B as above.
3. My data here is the probabilities of a, b, c in above?
4. How can I calculate the prior and posterior probability for this input?
5. What is the formula likelihood probability?
   P.S. Please consider guiding me undersanding the problem and solving it, my background is humanities and I am confused by the problem.